# Cannot add App Group containers entitlement to App ID

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7, ios-app-group

I'm building a Share Extension for my app and running into an issue when creating an App Group in Xcode.

I gave the App Group the name: **group.iosmoonsand.notes**

Xcode gave the following error when trying to *Add the "App Groups Containers" entitlement to your App ID*:

> Communication with Apple failed

This happens after I hit the *"Fix Issue"* button also.
This happens whether I have my iPhone connected and run the program on it or if I run the program in the Xcode Simulator.

Screenshot:
[image: App Groups Containers error]

The program runs when I run from the Xcode Simulator but when I try to Build/Run the program from my iPhone, I get the following error:

> Communication with Apple failed Your account does not have sufficient
>   permissions to modify containers.

​Screenshot:
[image: account does not have sufficient permissions]

I tried the following:

- ​R​emoving my account from the Xcode preferences and adding it again 
  ​
- Logging in to my developer account​ online.

​T​he same thing happens​ after I Clean/Build/Run the program from my iPhone.​

​I have a regular Apple ID. As Apple's Advanced App Capabilities page reads, I should have access to App Groups:
https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/